# Checking whether a list of points lie within a multipolygon (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, polygon, shapefile, shapely, geopandas

I am trying to check whether a list of points (which are stored in `df.Coords`) are found inside my shapefile (multipolygon). I wrote a code below, however, I realised that python only reads in the coordinates of my final layer of my multipolygon.

```
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

# read your shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader("C:\\filename.shp")

# get the shapes
shapes = r.shapes()

# build a shapely polygon from your shape
hold = []
for k in range(len(shapes)-1): 
    polygon = shape(shapes[k])
    hold.append(polygon)


    for x in df.Coords: 

        if polygon.contains(Point(x)):

            hold.append(x)
```

I tried to search for some code on stackoverflow (reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208546/check-if-a-point-falls-within-a-multipolygon-with-python/208574) and edited it (as shown below). However, I think I have edited it incorrectly.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPolygon
import shapefile 

polygon = shapefile.Reader("C:\\filename.shp") 

polygon = polygon.shapes() 

shpfilePoints = [ shape.points for shape in polygon ]

#print(shpfilePoints)


polygons = shpfilePoints
hold = []

for polygon in polygons:
    poly = Polygon(polygon)
    hold.append(poly)
    for x in hold: 

        for y in df.Coords:
            if x.contains(Point(y)):
                hold.append(y) 
print('hold',hold)
```

How can I check if my list of points (`df.Coords`) lie within my multipolygon (with 26 layers?)